# Remove unwanted characters in Codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have a database of products which I want to display on my CI site but it does have a **product title/name** table.

But the product URL in *productUrl table* contain the product name :

https://www.websitename.com/item/Dream-Feather-Autumn-Winter-Fleece-Oh-Yes-Letter-Harajuku-Print-Pullover-Thick-Loose-Women-Hoodies-Sweatshirt/32810266388.html

How do remove 'https://www.websitename.com/item/', the - symbol and html extension at the end '32810266388.html' so I'm able to display only

"Dream Feather Autumn Winter-Fleece Oh Yes Letter Harajuku Print Pullover Thick Loose Women Hoodies Sweatshirt"

Controller :

```
public function custom()
{

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Users');


    $params = array();
    $total_records = $this->Users->get_total();
```

Model :

```
public function get_current_page_records($limit, $start) 
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("SjohlLBzads_products");
        $this->db->join('SjohlLBzads_products_meta', 'SjohlLBzads_products_meta.post_id = SjohlLBzads_products.post_id');
        $this->db->join('SjohlLBzads_ali_meta', 'SjohlLBzads_ali_meta.post_id = SjohlLBzads_products.post_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    return false;
}
```

View :

```
<?php echo $data->productUrl ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://websitename.com"; // application/config/config.php
```

use URI segments:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);  // item
echo $this->uri->segment(2);  // Dream Feather Autumn Winter-Fleece Oh Yes Letter Harajuku Print Pullover Thick Loose Women Hoodies Sweatshirt
echo $this->uri->segment(3); // 32810266388.html OR 32810266388 (depends how .html got there)
```

So, in this very specific case:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(2);
or
$var = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

I'm quite confused by your controller/model/view code as they don't seem to have anything to do with the question.  If above doesn't answer your question, edit it and add more specifics and I'll update mine accordingly.